# How to handle when System.nanoTime() returns the same value between calls?

Tags: java, nanotime

This question is not intended as an attack upon `System.nanoTime()`.  I realize it is a surprisingly tricky method to use correctly.

What are some ways to deal with `System.nanoTime()` returning the same value between calls? Example: Multiple threads call `System.nanoTime()` and get the same value.

I am surprised how often I see this happen in my code base when running tests on Windows.  We use `nanoTime` to sort events that arrive across multiple threads.  Perhaps this is only a Windows issue and the Linux monotonic clock is more granular.

References:

- [Is System.nanoTime() guaranteed to return unique values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15493676/is-system-nanotime-guaranteed-to-return-unique-values)
- [Is System.nanoTime() completely useless?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510462/is-system-nanotime-completely-useless)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - "... We use nanoTime to sort events that arrive across multiple threads ..." Like to see you do that with a UUID.

Comment: why not use an atomic counter to sort the threads instead?

Comment: What exactly is the question? Are you looking for an alternative to nanoTime? Or a way to make nanoTime work for you? It seems like perhaps your model of the world (that only one thing happens during one tick) just doesn't fit with nanoTime. In reality, if you have multiple threads you cannot (without synchronization) produce a strict time-order for those events.

Comment: How big/long is a "tick"?  I am Intel i8 on Windows.  Are there docs for this per OS / hardware?

Comment: @ClaudioCorsi: That is an interesting idea.

Comment: @kevinarpe - Claudio's idea is the correct solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To explain why you're getting the same value, read the documentation a bit more closely:

> This method provides nanosecond precision, but not necessarily
>   nanosecond resolution (that is, how frequently the value changes) - no
>   guarantees are made except that the resolution is at least as good as
>   that of currentTimeMillis().

Your computer may not have enough clock resolution, so there could be a good chunk of time where `nanoTime` will return the same number.

As for your question

> What are some ways to deal with System.nanoTime() returning the same
>   value between calls?

I would suggest using some sort of an [atomic counter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomicvars.html), as Claudio Corsi suggests.

Comment: A new computer probably won't help.  Does any operating system actually provide a nanosecond-accurate `nanoTime()`?

Comment: `get a new computer` -- nice.  I have an 8-core Intel CPU; I doubt I need a new computer.  I am guessing this is a limitation on Windows.  I don't actually need nanosecond resolution -- but I am surprised how often the value is the same (a few times per day).

Comment: Can I have your old one after you replace it?

Comment: @DavidWallace Most standard operating systems probably won't provide nanosecond resolution, but there are probably some custom ones out there that will. It was a bit tongue in cheek. I had missed the part of the original question where he states his need, so I edited that suggestion out.

Comment: @kevinarpe The number of cores on your computer has little to do with clock resolution. It's either a hardware limitation or an OS limitation.

Comment: @kevinarpe If you are willing to use JNI you could make calls to access the higher precision timers on Windows. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx